# In the multinomial expansion of $(a+b+c+d)^8$, how many terms (monomials) have coefficient $\begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 2,4,0,2\end{pmatrix}$?

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

[image]

Can someone please explain why the ansewr is 12?
My current working:
Using the multinomial theorem, each term in the expanded (unsimplified) form would be uniquely determined by its distinct ordered partition of n, $x_1+x_2+...+x_m$.

And so the and so given n=8, the number of partitions and hence terms in the expanded multinomial is $\begin{pmatrix} 9 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$.

Is this reasoning correct? Because 126 total terms seems like a lot.
And, if according to my previous reasoning, were each unique partition of $n$ determines a separate multinomial coefficient (and hence term), wouldn't that mean that the term with $\begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 2,4,0,2\end{pmatrix}$ should be unique?

Comment: You have $~4~$ choices for which variable will be taken to the $~4$-th power.  Once this choice is made, you then have $~3~$ choices for which variable will be taken to the $~0$-th power.  So the pertinent *expressions* are $~a^4 \times b^0 \times c^2 \times d^2,~$ $~a^4 \times b^2 \times c^0 \times d^2, \cdots.$

Comment: You choose 2 variables to have exponent $2$, one to have exponent $4$, and the remaining one must have exponent $0$. Thus, the number of ways is $\binom{4}{2,1,1} = 12$.

Comment: What combinatorial combination of the multinomial coeffcient are you using for that? Is it Wikipedia's one:

The multinomial coefficients have a direct combinatorial interpretation, as the number of ways of depositing n distinct objects into m distinct bins, with ki
objects in the first bin, k, objects in the second bin, and so on.[1]

Comment: Basically, what is n=4 supposed to be in your answer? The 4 placeholders? Or the 4 numbers that we have. If it's the four numbers $\{2,4,0,2\}$, then going off of Wikipedia's interpretation, shouldn't we only have 3 distinct items $\{2,4,0\}$?

Comment: The $n=4$ comes from the four variables, i.e. the four lower entries in the original multinomial coefficient. In Wikipedia's language, the distinct exponents $(2,4,0)$ are the *bins*: 2 variables (objects) with exponent 2 (in the first bin), 1 variable with exponent 4 (in the second bin), and 1 variable with exponent 0 (last bin). Anyway, someone in this comment section should write an Answer; I'll do it if it's open for a day or so.